# Twisted IPullProducer what if I don't write anything?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I'm implementing a `IPullProducer`. Therefore the caller tells me when I have to produce data.

What if I'm temporarily unable to do that (waiting for some other event perhaps)?

Is there a way to tell the consumer that I can't produce data for a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An `IPullProducer` must always be able to synchronously produce data on demand; that's why the interface exists.

Perhaps you want an `IPushProducer` instead?

Comment: Bugger. Yes, I guess I'll end up using IPushProducer and add some glue code.